# Unable to access files created in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions

Lets say I create a file on the desktop, I can open it just by double clicking it. But when I move it to another location or paste it back to the desktop, I'm unable to gain access to that file. Moreover when I try to look into the properties, it says "You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions" whereas I'm very much logged in as the admin.

Comment: Try opening the file from command line using root login. Also, post the output of 'ls -l filename'.

Comment: Using root login? Not sure how to go about it, but I managed to access the output of 'ls -l filename' and this is what it shows `-rw------- 1 jarvis jarvis      4484 Dec 18 15:25 Ubuntu Tweaks`

Comment: Now i somehow managed to gain access. It seems to me that NTFS config tool is making some changes and thereby I'm not able to gain access to the files in that partition that I've selected for auto-mount. So i reconfigured it and all is set. But now when I try to make a shortcut of a file in question and place it on the desktop and restart the system, the link is broken and the shortcut is useless. Any clue what can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to take owner of that file as you supposed your account being admin.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and launch this command:

```
sudo chown <your_username> PATHTO/thefile
```

PATHTO is the path to your file, for example `/home/username/`.